# Why is there a total length field in the IPv4 header?

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4

Headers of IPv4 datagrams feature a field called *total length* coded on 16 bits. As there already is information about the *header length* of the datagram, having the total length seems redundant: it can be computed by substracting the header length from the total length of the data passed from the link layer.

Is that field really necessary?

Comment: How is a question regarding a design decision taken 40 years ago, 'practical' within the meaning of our [faq]?

Comment: IPv4 might have been designed 40 years ago, it is still quite used today, and new devices capable of connecting to networks are created every year. If this field could be ignored, it would be useful to do so.

Comment: It can't be ignored - lots of people are almost certainly checking it, since checking it is faster than subtracting the header length from the total length of the link layer.

Comment: Yes but how is knowing why useful in a practical manner from an administration point of view ? ie why is this topical for Server Fault ?

Comment: @lain I see, I think I understand the purpose of server fault better now. I will delete the question.

Comment: @Cian Your comment immediately made me think of what data leaks might happen if the IP header claimed a larger number of bytes than the link layer. Incidentally such a leak would be very similar to the heartbleed bug.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is yes - the IPv4 spec says its necessary, and so it is, at least for compatibility purposes.

The long answer is that some layer 2 transports will pad a datagram if it's under a particular size. the IP length header is important when this occurs, so that the layer two padding can be discarded.

Comment: Yikes: I totally forgot about padding. It also happens usually on odd-sized packets as most L2 protocols require an even-size packet.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an off-topic question, but I clearly remember asking the same question some 25 years ago in university when we discussed TCP/IP in networking 101.

The 2 answers I got then and which still makes sense where:

"At the time TCP/IP v4 was designed it was far from certain there wouldn't be an extension to IPv4 in the future that would make it more useful. So they left this in as an opening to future changes."

"If the software processing the TCP-IP packets has no knowledge of the L2 aspects of the data-transfer if needs a method to find the size. Either you put it in the packet or you provide a separate argument to the software that specifies the length. So you just might as well put it in the header in the first place."

(To illustrate the last: You mention this yourself in the question: "The total length of the data passed from the link layer" is the addiitonal argument.)